How to debug a DllNotFoundException thrown from an iPhone simulator or device for a native dependency?
I'm developing a .NET library that should work on Android, iOS, and desktop OSs. It works great everywhere -- except iOS. In fact on iOS I had it working for local deployment, but the Apple Store rejected an app based on it because the native dependency must be in an Apple "Framework".
So I did a bunch of research and learned about frameworks an xcframeworks, and refactored my nupkg to ship the native dependency within an xcframework structure. With that, the iOS csproj builds and appears to deploy both the .NET assembly and its native dependency with the app, but the app now throws DllNotFoundException when it attempts to load that native dependency.
The Visual Studio debug output window has only this on the problem:

**System.DllNotFoundException:** 'nerdbank_qrcodes'

How can I debug into this?
Or alternatively, what am I doing wrong? Here is the layout of my nupkg:
D:\PACKAGES\NUGET\NERDBANK.QRCODES\0.2.55-BETA-G209A879921
|   .nupkg.metadata
|   nerdbank.qrcodes.0.2.55-beta-g209a879921.nupkg
|   nerdbank.qrcodes.0.2.55-beta-g209a879921.nupkg.sha512
|   nerdbank.qrcodes.nuspec
|   README.md
|   THIRD_PARTY_DEPENDENCIES.txt
|   THIRD_PARTY_LICENSES.yml
|   
+---lib
|   +---net8.0
|   |       Nerdbank.QRCodes.dll
|   |       Nerdbank.QRCodes.xml
|   |       
|   +---net8.0-ios17.5
|   |   |   Nerdbank.QRCodes.dll
|   |   |   Nerdbank.QRCodes.xml
|   |   |   
|   |   \---Nerdbank.QRCodes.resources
|   |       |   manifest
|   |       |   
|   |       \---nerdbank_qrcodes.xcframework
|   |           |   Info.plist
|   |           |   
|   |           +---ios-arm64
|   |           |   \---nerdbank_qrcodes.framework
|   |           |           Info.plist
|   |           |           nerdbank_qrcodes
|   |           |           
|   |           \---ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
|   |               \---nerdbank_qrcodes.framework
|   |                       Info.plist
|   |                       nerdbank_qrcodes
|   |                       
|   \---net8.0-windows7.0
|           Nerdbank.QRCodes.dll
|           Nerdbank.QRCodes.xml
|           
\---runtimes
    +---android-arm64
    |   \---native
    |           libnerdbank_qrcodes.so
    |           
    +---android-x64
    |   \---native
    |           libnerdbank_qrcodes.so
    |           
    +---linux-arm64
    |   \---native
    |           libnerdbank_qrcodes.so
    |           
    +---linux-x64
    |   \---native
    |           libnerdbank_qrcodes.so
    |           
    +---osx-arm64
    |   \---native
    |           libnerdbank_qrcodes.dylib
    |           
    +---osx-x64
    |   \---native
    |           libnerdbank_qrcodes.dylib
    |           
    +---win-arm64
    |   \---native
    |           nerdbank_qrcodes.dll
    |           
    \---win-x64
        \---native
                nerdbank_qrcodes.dll

The native framework dll's are specially prepared using lipo and install_name_tool and chmod as follows:
# copy Info.plist and the binary into the appropriate .framework directory structure
# so that when NativeBindings.targets references it with ResolvedFileToPublish, it will be treated appropriately.
$RustTargetBaseDir = "$repoRoot/src/nerdbank-qrcodes/target"
$RustDylibFileName = "libnerdbank_qrcodes.dylib"
$DeviceRustOutput = "$RustTargetBaseDir/aarch64-apple-ios/$Configuration/$RustDylibFileName"
$SimulatorX64RustOutput = "$RustTargetBaseDir/x86_64-apple-ios/$Configuration/$RustDylibFileName"
$SimulatorArm64RustOutput = "$RustTargetBaseDir/aarch64-apple-ios-sim/$Configuration/$RustDylibFileName"

$DeviceFrameworkDir = "$repoRoot/bin/$Configuration/device/nerdbank_qrcodes.framework"
$SimulatorFrameworkDir = "$repoRoot/bin/$Configuration/simulator/nerdbank_qrcodes.framework"
New-Item -Path $DeviceFrameworkDir,$SimulatorFrameworkDir -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

Write-Host "Preparing Apple iOS and iOS-simulator frameworks"

Copy-Item $IntermediatePlistPath "$DeviceFrameworkDir/Info.plist"
Copy-Item $IntermediatePlistPath "$SimulatorFrameworkDir/Info.plist"
Write-Host "Created Info.plist with version $version"

if ($IsMacOS) {
    # Rename the binary that contains the arm64 architecture for device.
    lipo -create -output $DeviceFrameworkDir/nerdbank_qrcodes $DeviceRustOutput
    install_name_tool -id "@rpath/nerdbank_qrcodes.framework/nerdbank_qrcodes" "$DeviceFrameworkDir/nerdbank_qrcodes"
    chmod +x "$DeviceFrameworkDir/nerdbank_qrcodes"

    # Create a universal binary that contains both arm64 and x64 architectures for simulator.
    lipo -create -output $SimulatorFrameworkDir/nerdbank_qrcodes $SimulatorX64RustOutput $SimulatorArm64RustOutput
    install_name_tool -id "@rpath/nerdbank_qrcodes.framework/nerdbank_qrcodes" "$SimulatorFrameworkDir/nerdbank_qrcodes"
    chmod +x "$SimulatorFrameworkDir/nerdbank_qrcodes"
}

Full context

It turns out that the last thing I was missing was changing the library name I use in DllImportAttribute:
#if IOS
    // https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/21238
    private const string LibraryName = "@rpath/nerdbank_qrcodes.framework/nerdbank_qrcodes";
#else
    private const string LibraryName = "nerdbank_qrcodes";
#endif

